# How to implement sklearns StratifiedKfold with fastai?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, fast-ai

I am in the APTOS 2019 kaggle competition and am trying to ensemble on 5 folds but I am having issues with correctly implementing StratifiedKFold.

I have tried googling on the fastai discussions but I dont see any solutions. 
I am using the fastai library and have a pretrained model.

```
def get_df():
    base_image_dir = os.path.join('..', 'input/aptos2019-blindness- 
    detection/')
    train_dir = os.path.join(base_image_dir,'train_images/')
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_image_dir, 'train.csv'))
    df['path'] = df['id_code'].map(lambda x: 
    os.path.join(train_dir,'{}.png'.format(x)))
    df = df.drop(columns=['id_code'])
    df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) #shuffle dataframe
    test_df = pd.read_csv('../input/aptos2019-blindness- 
    detection/sample_submission.csv')
    return df, test_df

df, test_df = get_df()

random_state = np.random.seed(2019)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=random_state, shuffle=True)

X = df['path']
y = df['diagnosis']

#getting the splits
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
   print('##')
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
   train = X_train, y_train
   test = X_test, y_test
   train_list = [list(x) for x in train]
   test_list  = [list(x) for x in test]


data = (ImageList.from_df(df=df,path='./',cols='path') 
    .split_by_rand_pct(0.2) 
    .label_from_df(cols='diagnosis',label_cls=FloatList) 
    .transform(tfms,size=sz,resize_method=ResizeMethod.SQUISH,padding_mode='zeros') 
    .databunch(bs=bs,num_workers=4) 
    .normalize(imagenet_stats)  
   )

learn = Learner(data, 
            md_ef, 
            metrics = [qk], 
            model_dir="models").to_fp16()
learn.data.add_test(ImageList.from_df(test_df,
                             '../input/aptos2019-blindness-detection',
                                  folder='test_images',
                                  suffix='.png'))
```

I want to use the folds I got from the skf.split in training my model but I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways this can be done.

1. Use 'split_by_idxs' with the indexes

```
    data = (ImageList.from_df(df=df,path='./',cols='path')
        .split_by_idxs(train_idx=train_index, valid_idx=test_index) 
        .label_from_df(cols='diagnosis',label_cls=FloatList) 
        .transform(tfms,size=sz,resize_method=ResizeMethod.SQUISH,padding_mode='zeros') 
        .databunch(bs=bs,num_workers=4) 
        .normalize(imagenet_stats)  
       )
```

2. Use 'split_by_list'

```
   il = ImageList.from_df(df=df,path='./',cols='path')

   data = (il.split_by_list(train=il[train_index], valid=il[test_index]) 
       .label_from_df(cols='diagnosis',label_cls=FloatList) 
       .transform(tfms,size=sz,resize_method=ResizeMethod.SQUISH,padding_mode='zeros') 
       .databunch(bs=bs,num_workers=4) 
       .normalize(imagenet_stats)  
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a chunk of code. Hope this helps.

```
# creating a KFold object with 5 splits 
folds = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 10)

# specify range of hyperparameters
# Set the parameters by cross-validation
hyper_params = [ {'gamma': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [5,10]}]


# specify model
model = SVC(kernel="rbf")

# set up GridSearchCV()
model_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, 
                        param_grid = hyper_params, 
                        scoring= 'accuracy', 
                        cv = folds, 
                        verbose = 1,
                        return_train_score=True)      

# fit the model
model_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am using an EfficientNet-B5 and I would like to keep the line with "data" . I was told by another user to use split_by_index but I am not sure on how to.